# Why isn't package name correct in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

My package name is not correct in AndroidManifest.xml

AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="Mahrek"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I looked at users' files on StackOverflow. It says in their files but not in mine.

Comment: look for agp8 and gradle namespace. for some reason it replaces package name in manifest.

Comment: remove package name from manifest.. Just use namespace in buildgradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your package name in the manifest tag i.e `package="youpackagenamehere"`

your manifest tag should look like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="youpackagenamehere">
```